# How to add spacing between bootstrap buttons like in example?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, spacing

There is a comprehensive example of bootstrap button on the official website, but I can't figure out why there is a spacing between the buttons and how to do the same?
Any browser debug tool does not show anything: there are some top and bottom margins but nothing about horizontal spacing! Can anyone explain?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/
[image: bootstrap button example]

Comment: That should be a regular spacing for inline elements. If you inspect them you will see they have `display: inline-block;`... just put a blank space in between them.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using? 3 or 4? Lol nevermind, the link... derp.

Comment: Spacing between buttons is because of `hover` event

Answer (score 1):

Just add in your styles something like :

```css
button.btn {
    margin: 0 1px;
}
```

But be sure that it doesn't impact other styles that you wrote before

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap 4, you could also add the class "mr-1" to your buttons; that way you don't have to change the css (unless you want to :) ).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to their reboot stylesheet which styles the documentation you are looking at.

If you pull up a google element inspector their is actually a total of 2 maring and 6px padding on the left and right side of the buttons. This will not apply to the buttons that you use in your templates.

Answer (score 0):

The spacing you are describing is what happens when you have multiple `display:inline-block` elements with the code that creates them each on their own line.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>These buttons will appear with spacing between them.</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>

<hr />

<p>These buttons will not.</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
```

There are any number of ways to add the spacing manually using the `.m-*-*` utility class or other custom CSS.  Or you can simply output your HTML with each button on a new line.